# Read strings from file and give option to choose installation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to make Steam backups installer. However, Steam allow to user make multiple library folders which makes installation difficult.

There are a few tasks that I want to perform.

1. Installer should identify path from registry to identify where Steam is installed.
2. The resulting path from registry open file

   ```
   X:\Steam\config\config.vdf
   ```

   and read value of `"BaseInstallFolder_1"`, `"BaseInstallFolder_2"`, `"BaseInstallFolder_3"` and etc.

   Example of `config.vdf`:

   ```
   "NoSavePersonalInfo"        "0"
   "MaxServerBrowserPingsPerMin"       "0"
   "DownloadThrottleKbps"      "0"
   "AllowDownloadsDuringGameplay"      "0"
   "StreamingThrottleEnabled"      "1"
   "AutoUpdateWindowStart"     "-1"
   "AutoUpdateWindowEnd"       "-1"
   "LastConfigstoreUploadTime"     "1461497849"
   "BaseInstallFolder_1"       "E:\\Steam_GAMES"
   ```
3. The resulting path or paths of the file `config.vdf` bring in `DirEdit`
4. If user have multiple paths to the folder in different locations then give option select through DirTreeView or Radiobuttons.

   How it should look like:

   [image]

   ---

I know how to identify Steam path

```pascal
WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExpandConstant('{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam,InstallPath|{pf}\Steam}')+ '\steamapps\common\gamename';
```

But it is difficult to perform other tasks

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: These are two separate questions: parsing the file and implementing the predefined paths selection. Ask them separately.

Answer (score 3):

To parse the `config.vdf` file:

- Load the file using [`LoadStringsFromFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile).
- And use string functions like [`Copy`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_copy), [`Pos`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_pos), [`Delete`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_delete), [`CompareText`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparetext) to parse it.
- To keep the results use `array of string` (or predefined `TArrayOfString`). To allocate the array, use [`SetArrayLength`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setarraylength).

The code may be like:

```pascal
function ParseSteamConfig(FileName: string; var Paths: TArrayOfString): Boolean;
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  I: Integer;
  Line: string;
  P: Integer;
  Key: string;
  Value: string;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines);

  Count := 0;

  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
  begin
    Line := Trim(Lines[I]);
    if Copy(Line, 1, 1) = '"' then
    begin
      Delete(Line, 1, 1);
      P := Pos('"', Line);
      if P > 0 then
      begin
        Key := Trim(Copy(Line, 1, P - 1));
        Delete(Line, 1, P);
        Line := Trim(Line);
        Log(Format('Found key "%s"', [Key]));

        if (CompareText(
              Copy(Key, 1, Length(BaseInstallFolderKeyPrefix)),
              BaseInstallFolderKeyPrefix) = 0) and
           (Line[1] = '"') then
        begin
          Log(Format('Found base install folder key "%s"', [Key]));
          Delete(Line, 1, 1);
          P := Pos('"', Line);
          if P > 0 then
          begin
            Value := Trim(Copy(Line, 1, P - 1));
            StringChange(Value, '\\', '\');
            Log(Format('Found base install folder "%s"', [Value]));
            Inc(Count);
            SetArrayLength(Paths, Count);
            Paths[Count - 1] := Value;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```